# Username Validation in Power Pages user registration page

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-platform, powerapps-portal

I am currently working with Power Pages and Power Portal in the D365 Power Platform. To enforce a restriction on usernames to allow only alphanumeric characters, I have been using the Authentication/UserManager/UserValidator/AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames setting. However, I recently attempted to use the Authentication/UserManager/UserValidator/AllowedUserNameCharacters setting to achieve the other characters validation, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

I would like to know if the AllowedUserNameCharacters setting is available  to restrict in Power Pages/Power Portal same as .net core, or if there is an alternative setting or configuration option available for this purpose.

Any insights, workarounds, or code examples would be greatly appreciated.